# How do I make Title display above the horizon chart instead of below in cubism.js?

Tags: cubism.js

I'm using .alias, but when the horizon chart is rendered, it displays the Title: Chart Foo on the lower right hand side of the chart. How do I make the Title display above the chart?

```
        // Create metrics
        var metrics = [
          graphite.metric("foo.bar").alias("Chart " + "Foo"),
          graphite.metric("baz.qux").alias("Chart " + "Baz")
        ];

        d3.select(".span9").call(function(div) {
          div.select(".new").call(context.axis().orient("top"));
          div.select(".new").selectAll(".horizon")
           .data(metrics)
           .enter().append("div")
           .attr("class", "charts")
           .call(context.horizon().height(100));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to modify the css for the `.horizon .title`.

e.g.

```
.horizon .title {
    bottom: 90;
    margin: 0px 6px;
}
```